# Flat extension of noetherian rings and formal power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, power-series

Let $A \to B$ be a flat homomorphism of Noetherian rings. Is it true that it induces a flat homomorphism of formal power series $A[[x]] \to B[[x]]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

In order to prove this we use Theorem 22.3 from Matsumura, CRT.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I\subset R$ an ideal, and $M$ an $R$-module. Suppose that $R$ is noetherian. Moreover, there is a noetherian $R$-algebra $S$ such that $M$ is a finite $S$-module, and $IS\subset J(S)$ (this is sufficient for $M$ to be $I$-adically separated). If $M/IM$ is $R/I$-flat and $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(R/I,M)=0$, then $M$ is $R$-flat.

Now consider $R=A[[X]]$, $I=(X)$, and $S=M=B[[X]]$.

Answer (score 2):

It is true: $A[[X]]$ and $B[[X]]$ are the completions of the noetherian rings $R=A[X]$  and $S=B[X]$ for the $X$-adic topology.

Now, according to *Bourbaki, Commutative algebra*, Ch. III, Graduations, filtrations and topologies, §5 n°4, prop.4, for any finite $S$-module $M$, the following are equivalent:

(a) $M$ is $R$-flat,

(b) $\widehat{\!M\mkern-1mu}$ is $R$-flat,

(c) $\widehat{\!M\mkern-1mu}$ is $\,\widehat{\!R}$-flat.