# extension of formal power series rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I saw a question about flat extension o formal power series of Noetherian rings at here: 
[Flat extension of noetherian rings and formal power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350038/flat-extension-of-noetherian-rings-and-formal-power-series). The problem is:

> Let $A \to B$ be a flat homomorphism of Noetherian rings. Is it true that it induces a flat homomorphism of formal power series $A[[x]] \to B[[x]]$?

In the case both $A$ and $B$ are local, we got another flat homomorphism  criteria for two local rings $(R=A[[X]], m)$ and $(S=B[[X]], n)$ that we only need $\mathrm{Tor}^{R}_1(S, R/m) = 0$ with $m$ is maximal ideal of $R$. By the exact sequence: $$0 \to m \to R \to R/m \to 0$$ we get long exact sequence: $$\mathrm{Tor}^{R}_1(S, R/m) \to S \otimes m \to S \otimes R \to S \otimes R/m \to 0,$$ then we have: $$\mathrm{Tor}^{R}_1(S, R/m) \to S \otimes m \to S \to S/mS \to 0.$$ 
So, to prove that $\mathrm{Tor}^{R}_1(S, R/m) = 0$, we need to prove $S \otimes m \cong mS$ to get exact sequence $0 \to mS \to S \to S/mS \to 0$ then conclude $\mathrm{Tor}^{R}_1(S, R/m) = 0$. But how can we prove that $S \otimes m \cong mS$ ? We only know that $B$ is flat over $A$. Or is there another way to solve this problem without using this flat criteria ?

I see that we have $S \otimes_{k} k \cong kS $ ($k$ is maximal ideal of $A$) because $S$ is flat over $A$ so by extension to $R$ could we get $S \otimes_{R} kR \cong kRS$ then $S \otimes_{R} m \cong mS $ ?